# How to know if the user has entered his steps manually

Tags: fitbit

I am web developer, and now develop Webapp, which fetches how many steps user walked per a day by Fitbit Api.

My question:

How i can know if the user had entered steps Manual, and in practice no walked any more!

now i used the api request, and sum the respones as follow:

$apiRequest = $provider->getAuthenticatedRequest(
    Fitbit::METHOD_GET,
    Fitbit::BASE_FITBIT_API_URL . '/1/user/-/activities/steps/date/'.$startDateStr.'/'.$endDateStr.'.json',
    $accessToken,
    ['headers' => [Fitbit::HEADER_ACCEPT_LANG => 'en_US'], [Fitbit::HEADER_ACCEPT_LOCALE => 'en_US']]
);

$apiRespone["activities-steps"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using tracker, what the user manually entered will be ignoriered:

```
/1/user/-/activities/tracker/steps/date/startDate/endDate.json
```

but when user cheat; you can not control that; for example:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VJnSK4htwoc

Comment: Thanks Man, Working perfect .. Saved my day .. :)